# Pointer address changed - function

Tags: c++, function, pointers

I have this code:

```
class pointLineVCN
{
public:
    int v, vc, vn;

    pointLineVCN(){};
    pointLineVCN(int v, int vc, int vn)
    {
        this->v = v;
        this ->vc = vc;
        this->vn = vn;
    }
};

pointLineVCN* newPoint;
void Triangulation3D(pointLineVCN* point, short numOfPoints)
{
    newPoint = new pointLineVCN[(numOfPoints - 2)  * 3];
    //Code which changes newPoint

    point = newPoint;
    cout<<point<<endl;
}
```

And on the main:

```
pointLineVCN *vertices = new pointLineVCN[meshes[meshNum].face[*positionSaverFN].numOfPoints];

for (int i = 0; i < meshes[meshNum].face[*positionSaverFN].numOfPoints; i++)
{
    sscanf(bufferStr.c_str(), "%i/%i/%i", &faceVec, &faceTex, &faceNor);

    vertices[i].v = faceVec - 1;
    vertices[i].vc = faceTex - 1;
    vertices[i].vn = faceNor - 1;
}
Triangulation3D(vertices, meshes[meshNum].face[*positionSaverFN].numOfPoints);
cout<<vertices<<endl;
```

The problem is `point` address changes after Triangulation3D ends. On the `cout` calls the output is two different addresses.

I have seen another question about this problem and the solution is using `pointLineVCN** point` but it did not helped.

Comment: -1 for "Here's the code, it's not doing what I want, fix it."

Comment: In the function declaration, use `void Triangulation3D(pointLineVCN *& point, short numOfPoints)` instead.

Answer (score 1):

It's *changing* because **you're changing it**:

```
point = newPoint;
```

if you don't want to change it, then don't do it.

Comment: I want this new address. After the function ends the address back to the first one before this line.

Comment: @DarkStorm97 Then you can change Triangulation3D to `void Triangulation3D(pointToLineVCN*& point, short numOfPoints)` to make your change visible to the calling site. But really review your code, you leak memory and your code structure is really complicated (e.g. use vector instead of array)